# Why is "CLSIDFromProgID" not working in some cases?

Tags: c++, object, com, registry, progid

I am working on program using COM object. I try to get CLSID from ProgID of COM object. The ProgID is "ProvisioningWapDPURemote" and I am using this funtion "CLSIDFromProgID".
The code is as follows.

```
CLSID clsid;
LPCOLESTR pProgID = L"ProvisioningWapDPURemote";
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(pProgID, &clsid);
```

When I execute this code, I can't get error code "Invalid class string". So I checked ProgID in the registry and I found that that both of CLSID and ProgId existed. I don't understand what is wrong here. I tried this function with another ProgId, and surprisingly it works. What's going on here? Anyone knows about this, please give some answers. Thanks.

Comment: If this code's runnning as x86 process, it cannot see what's in 64bit COM registry. And if this code's runnning as x64 process, it cannot see what's in 32bit COM registry

Comment: Thanks for your answer but thing is no like that. I still get error code "Invalid class string".

Answer (score -3):

You can try this code:

```
system("title AimBot");
Sleep(140);
HWND Aim = (FindWindowA(NULL, "AimBot"));    
ShowWindow(Aim, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. I think the code above has no concern with the problem.